# How to summarize pdf file into plain text, and create and place new file on desktop?

Tags: python, pdf, text, pypdf

I want to automatically turn pdf files into text, and then take that output to save a file on my desktop.

Example:

-- pdf converted text: "HELLO WORLD"

-- save file on desktop on a .txt file with "HELLO WORLD" saved.

I have done:

```py
fp = open('/Users/zain/Desktop', 'pdf_summary')
fp.write(text)
```

I thought this would save my file on the desktop given the input (text) which I used as the variable to house the converted text.

Full Code:

```py
from PyPDF2 import PdfReader

reader = PdfReader("/Users/zain/Desktop/Week2_POL305_Manfieldetal.pdf")
text = ""
for page in reader.pages:
text += page.extract_text() + "\n"

print(text)

fp = open('/Users/zain/Desktop', 'pdf_summary')
fp.write(text)

fp.write(text)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PDF may consist of all sorts of things, not only text.
You therefore have to explicitly extract text from a PDF - if that is what you want.

In package PyMuPDF you could do it this way:

```py
import fitz  # import pymupdf
import pathlib

doc=fitz.open("input.pdf")
text = "\n".join([page.get_text() for page in doc])
pathlib.Path("input.txt").write_bytes(text.encode())  # supports non ASCII text
```

Comment: This worked great, thank you! Do you have resources on how to create a small application that I can create with a GUI to drag and drop files locally on my Mac? I am in the process of learning python and this would be my first project.

Comment: Not sure about a GUI being the best solution, but you could make a batch (CLI) script that invokes your Python program. Drag a PDF onto the script icon on your desktop to invoke. In the Python program, add line `import sys` at the top and change `fitz.open("input.pdf")` to `fitz.open(sys.argv[1])`. This causes the dragged filename to be passed to your program. The batch script should contain something like `python yourprogram.py $1` (not sure about Mac to be honest).

Answer (score 0):

This works for me.

```
from PyPDF2 import PdfReader

#path to pdf file
reader=PdfReader(r'C:\Users\zain\Desktop\Week2_POL305_Manfieldetal.pdf')

text = ""

for page in reader.pages:
    text += page.extract_text() + '\n'

#path to save file on desktop
#you can keep txt, leave nothing, or change it to another file type
fp = open(r'C:\Users\zain\Desktop\pdf_summary.txt','a')
fp.writelines(text)
```

Comment: File "/Users/zain/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/TEST_pdftotext.py", line 4
    reader = PdfReader("\Users\zain\Desktop\Week2_POL305_Manfieldetal.pdf")
                                                                          ^
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 0-1: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape

Comment: I keep on getting this error here

Comment: @zainalisaqib you need to include the 'r' before the string to tell it that it's reading a file path